# What decides columns in Azure queues?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-queues, lokad-cqrs, cloudfx

I'm using Azure Queue storage.  I just upgraded from using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.  I've also recently changed over from using Lokad to CloudFx.  At some point in the process, I started getting some more columns in Queue storage, including a duplicate Dequeue Count.

[image: Azure Storage Explorer snapshot]

I can't figure out how those columns are getting created.  Why are there two Dequeue Count columns?

Comment: Did you also upgrade the Azure SDK and storage client library?  Where are you seeing these columns?

Comment: @knightpfhor, no we have not upgraded our SDK (got lots of errors when we tried).  Yes, we have upgraded the storage client library.  I was seeing the columns in Azure Storage Explorer.  See accepted answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns have nothing to do with the internal schema of the message. They display management metadata which is specific to the queue. "Dequeue Count" indicates how many times clients have attempted to dequeue the message.

The duplicate column issue looks to me like a UI bug in the management tool.

Comment: Correct you are.  Coworker looked at the queue through a different, 3rd party tool and all the columns showed up great.  Weird.  Thanks!